# A limited thread & creating more on demand

Tags: java

I have a program where the user fetches some data from the stored files. That can be 1, 2, 3, 10, 50, 100, 1000 etc. files. I want that files to be fetched via separated thread. But when the thread reaches e.g. 50th file then a new thread is created. And if it's not enough then 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc. threads are created until all the data from the files would be retrieved.

So, the question is: how to make a limit of 50 files to check for 1 thread and how to create new ones for the next files processing? Maybe some ExecutorService, synchronizer, or something which I have some difficulties to understand yet...

Comment: Can you count the files before you start? Then you can create the correct number of threads from the outset, which would be much more efficient.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, I can actually count the files that I will need before processing. So if I know the amount of files then I should just create a necessary amount of threads. But if I don't? Is there any way to create the threads on the fly?